# On dit la qualité de vie; pourquoi pas la qualité de la vie?

Tags: grammaire

On dit « la qualité de vie ». Pourquoi l'article s'évite-t-il dans cette phrase alors qu'on dit « la qualité du lait » ?

Answer (score 9):

Les expressions « **qualité de vie** »  et « **qualité de la vie** » ont été en concurrence à la fin des années 1960, période où leur usage a explosé :

[image]

La deuxième a d'abord été plus populaire mais c'est aujourd'hui l'expression « **qualité de vie** » qui s'est imposée, probablement par analogie avec les expressions apparentées « **niveau de vie** », « **condition de vie** » et « **espérance de vie** » qui étaient déjà établies depuis parfois plusieurs décennies :

[image]

D'autres expressions où vie ne prends pas non plus d'article sont apparues à la même époque comme « **cycle de vie** » et « **fin de vie** » :

[image]

Dans certains cas, les deux variantes ont des sens différents:

> **condition de vie** = La manière dont les gens vivent (logement, revenus, environnement, etc.).
>
> **condition de la vie** = Ce qui rend la vie humaine/animale/végétale possible.
>
> **durée de vie** = combien de temps dure en moyenne la vie de quelqu'un/quelque chose.
>
> **durée de la vie** = combien de temps la vie de quelqu'un/quelque chose a duré.

[image]

En conclusion, la règle était autrefois la présence d'un article. L'absence d'article est associée à des expressions figées, essentiellement présentes dans le vocabulaire des statistiques et qui sont apparues plus ou moins récemment. Par exemple « **sciences de la vie** » ne concerne pas les statistiques et conserve bien son article.

Ce n'est cependant pas une règle absolue car l'on trouve aussi « **coût de la vie** » (statistiques) alors que ***coût de vie** est inusité.

Comment: Très intéressant concernant les usages, mais qu'en est-il du "pourquoi", grammaticalement ?

Comment: Super réponse. Quelle source avez-vous pour l'historique de la popularité relative de ces termes ?

Comment: Sources (graphiques ngram) ajoutés. c.f. https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: @Random Tentative d'explication du « pourquoi » ajoutée.

Comment: _DHLF/Rey_ (2012) atteste 1970 pour _qualité de la vie_.

Comment: Au temps, pour moi et je l'avais plussoyée à l'époque ! Voir que dans le milieu scolaire on impose la présence de l'article ça me fait fulminer !

Answer (score 1):

L'article est omis de manière fréquente, et c'est accepté, aussi bien à l'oral qu'à l'écrit. La forme avec un article défini reste toujours possible mais moins usitée(ou dans des cas précis).

D'autres exemples:

- la liberté de pensée;
- le mode de pensée;
- le mode de vie;
- le pouvoir d'achat;
- le pouvoir de persuasion;
- la force de séduction;
- le coût de restitution.

On peut faire plusieurs remarques:

- le deuxième terme ou même les deux ont des sens **abstraits**, ne sont pas des objets concrets;
- souvent d'ailleurs, **le deuxième terme a un verbe associé**: dans le cas d'un verbe, on pourrait dire: *la liberté pour penser, le mode pour penser, le mode pour vivre (ou selon lequel vivre), le pouvoir pour acheter, pour persuader, pour séduire, pour restituer ...*
- le premier est peut-être limité à un ensemble réduit ou en tous cas compatible avec un verbe substantivé: qualité, pouvoir, mode, ...

Mais, on ne dit pas:
- la force, le pouvoir de gentillesse, de tristesse, ... (qui n'ont pas de verbe associé).

la forme est assez rare avec des choses concrètes **dénombrables** (je n'ai pas trouvé d'exemple), sauf expressions figées.

Comme dit précédemment (avec le lait), on peut toutefois le faire avec un **indénombrable**, mais peut-être pour des mots réduits: la qualité de soja, la quantité d'eau, le niveau de son (préférer du son), ...

**En conclusion, plusieurs schémas possibles:**

1 : mot de mesure (qualité, quantité, niveau, ...) + de + mot indénombrable (mot concret, ou signification abstraite)

2 : n'importe quel mot (compatible) + de + verbe substantivé

3 : des expressions figées: *hauteur de crête*, *ligne d'horizon*, ...

Answer (score 0):

- *La qualité de la vie* que l'on mène : il s'agit d'une vie particulière qui concerne une personne singulière (une vie parmi d'autres vies).
- *La qualité de vie* : la qualité d'*être* que tout un chacun peut avoir, la vie n'est plus un avoir personnel, mais un état général du vivant.

[*En regardant les exemples*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=qualit%C3%A9%20de%20vie%2C%20qualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20vie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cqualit%C3%A9%20de%20vie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cqualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20vie%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cqualit%C3%A9%20de%20vie%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cqualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20vie%3B%2Cc0), on s'aperçoit que l'usage se détermine selon le contexte :

- *la qualité de la vie* de personne(s) particulière(s).
- la *qualité de vie* d'un groupe ou d'une société,

Pour ce qui concerne la seconde partie de la question :

- *La qualité du lait* : le lait est une matière que l'on dénombre en litres, dont on peut définir le taux de crème, qui a une saveur que la langue et le palais reconnaissent selon l'animal qui l'a produit.
- [*la qualité **de** lait*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22qualit%C3%A9%20de%20lait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr&ei=7-F6V9fJNqbZgAba8pnYCw#q=%22qualit%C3%A9%20de%20lait%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&start=10) ne peut convenir que pour les ouvrages techniques où le lait n'est plus défini en tant qu'aliment, mais comme entité industrielle.
  Dans l'usage courant le lait n'est pas un type, une idée, un principe, une abstraction : quand deux personnes comparent deux types de lait, elles ne diront pas *la qualité de lait de vache*, comme un technicien de l'agro-alimentaire peut le formuler dans un rapport, mais *la qualité du lait de vache est différente de celle du lait de brebis*.

Comment: Et un de plus qui se moque de la charte du site qui demande de justifier les votes négatifs... pour améliorer la qualité des réponses...

Comment: Je ne fais pas partie des *downvoters* mais peut-être est-ce « la matière que l'on dénombre » qui est dure à avaler ;-) pour certains.

Comment: @jlliagre ... j'ai laissé tel quel parce qu'*un litre de lait* tiré au pis de la vache, de la chèvre, de la brebis, de la bufflonne, de madame zébu, ou d'une bisonne (si tu arrives à la traire) ... c'est plus nourrissant que les règles grammaticales ... Et c'est peut-être mon ignorance de ces dernières que l'on me reproche? ... va savoir :) .

Comment: @Onaeu. Vos commentaires m'intéressent, et, si je me suis amusé à broder sur *la qualité du lait*, c'est bien qu'elle fait partie de la question... et que je ne vois pas de règle grammaticale qui pourrait convenir. J'aimerais savoir si les motivations des votes négatifs sont identiques aux vôtres, et si la seconde partie de ma réponse tient la route.

Comment: @Onaeu. J'espère que vos remarques m'ont permis d'améliorer ma réponse :)

Comment: La réponse est tout à fait intéressante, d'où mon +1, qui compense les votes négatifs (mais c'est la vie !). Sur le trolling, justement, cet interessant article:  http://scottbarrykaufman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/trolls-just-want-to-have-fun.pdf

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina -- Systématiquement je rappelle la nétiquette, sur un site qui pourtant est parfaitement modéré, moins à cause des troll, j'ai passé l'âge de refaire le monde, que pour essayer d'améliorer mes réponses. N'étant ni universitaire, ni grammairien et encore moins reconnu par une académie littéraire, je sais, comme Socrate, que je ne sais rien... mais que je dois tout à la francophonie, qui est mon seul sabir... acquis uniquement par la pratique et  l'expérience ; alors, si cela peut aider ceux qui s'intéressent à la vie du français, je n'aurais pas 'clavioté' pour rien.

Answer (score 0):

L'organisation mondiale de la santé utilise le terme *qualité de la vie*, tout comme plusieurs instances gouvernementales (du moins au Canada).

"Qualité de vie" semble être un anglicisme, calqué de *quality of life*.

(*edit*): il semblerait que le gouvernement français ait utilisé qualité de *la* vie également: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minist%C3%A8re_de_la_Qualit%C3%A9_de_la_vie

Comment: On a _qualité de la vie_ au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qualit%C3%A9), même chose au [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/qualit%c3%a9/65477/locution?q=qualit%c3%a9+de+vie#165726) ; quant au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8452705) il a une fiche de 1997 qui contient aussi _qualité de vie_. Vous pouvez choisir d'incorporer ces liens dans votre propos et d'élaborer davantage.